# Should a user always see their ad filtering preferences?

Tags: mobile, filter

I'm developing an app that shows ads near you. In order to ensure that users see the most relevant ads, they can filter their ads. Should a user see their filter preferences at all times, while viewing ads?

Here is how my design looks now:

[image]

And

[image]

Ad categories are shown in tags below the ads. The top left circular button is the user and the top right is going to be chats. Once you click on the '+' button on an ad you can chat with whomever posted it.

Answer (score 1):

In the case that a users' filters are really wide open (e.g. wanting to see all offers within 50km, or from $20-200) it might be more useful to **highlight the details of the actual offer** the user is currently viewing.

I imagine the "Tap to read more" would contain these specifics, but I think surfacing them in the initial results view would be more useful when browsing.

For instance, in your first screenshot, I don't know how much those parts actually cost—they could be anywhere from $68-200, which is kind of a wide range.

Comment: Highlighting the details of an offer makes sense. I think you misunderstood the card (or is it an example of bad ui/ux?) since it is a service depending on what you are looking for the price changes. Anyway, the tap to read more would contain all that information yes. How do you think I can include different prices in the scene I showed you? Since I'm so limited in space I don't know what to do, maybe more 'tags'?

Comment: @Levon My mistake! Yes, I had thought those were your filter options rather than the specific item’s details. I’m sure that’d be clearer to someone who had gone through the process of adding filters/ranges and seeing those specific values show up. In that case, I think what you have looks good.

Answer (score 1):

The `inline` tap to read more is giving me more of a heart attack than the filters. In situations like this, I like to think of the immediate response to an organisation that will also be doing this. Facebook’s Marketplace is a good start.

I can select the filters, and then my selection loads. When I scroll, the filter selection disappears. I think it is because we assume the user will have remembered their selection. Even if they do select *many* options, all of the results will still be relevant to them otherwise they wouldn’t have selected them in the first place.

Don’t forget on a mobile application, space is always of the essence. It is so precious these days. Thinking back, online shopping, clothes, electronics etc, the filters that are applied are out of view, but, can be accessed in one gesture.

Marketplace by Facebook hides the filters on scroll down, but scroll back up and the filter ‘trigger’ button slides in from the top.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Facebook's Marketplace chose a nice approach to solve the problem. One question, how would you improve the inline tap to read more, and whats wrong with it?

Comment: @Levon I'd put it on a new line ;-) but, it is your design, not mine ;-)